Problems with OpenCV drawFrameAxes() function
I noticed an issue with the cv::drawFrameAxes() function. When the triad lines reach far outside of the image, the lines are distorted, no longer coincident with the axes as they should appear.
I was working on detecting charuco boards using OpenCV+Contrib 4.10.0. Once I have detected and estimated its pose, I am trying to plot the axis; however, I can see different axis if I change their lengths even if everything remains the same. I am providing a sample image, camera params and code to reproduce. Take a look a the attached images as well. The axis even 'break', or keeps only the outline without the fill, at longer axis length, e.g. 10.
I get the same results if I do this on simulated images as well as OpenCV (opencv-python) 4.7.0.72.



import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# camera params after calibration
mtx = np.array([[3341.0930071 ,    0.        , 2020.04757797],
   [   0.        , 3332.54238818, 1108.10670945],
   [   0.        ,    0.        ,    1.        ]])
   
dist = np.array([-0.10474984,  0.04565679,  0.00948721,  0.        ,  0.        ])

img_rgb = cv2.imread("some img")
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# board info
dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_100)
board = cv2.aruco.CharucoBoard((7, 5), 0.055, 0.041, dictionary)

params = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(dictionary, params)

# detect markers and charuco corners
marker_corners, marker_ids, rejectedCandidates = detector.detectMarkers(img)

ret, charucoCorners, charucoIds = cv2.aruco.interpolateCornersCharuco(marker_corners, marker_ids, img, board)

ret, rvec, tvec = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseCharucoBoard(charucoCorners, charucoIds, board, mtx, dist, None, None)

# start plotting
axis_size = 0.1
result_short = cv2.drawFrameAxes(np.copy(img_rgb), mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, axis_size)

axis_size = 5
result_long = cv2.drawFrameAxes(np.copy(img_rgb), mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, axis_size)

# plot
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(result_short)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(result_long)

plt.show()

result_both = cv2.drawFrameAxes(np.copy(img_rgb), mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, 0.2)
result_both = cv2.drawFrameAxes(result_both, mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, 2)

Edit: Changed the example picture to an uncropped version, changed variable name mtx2 to mtx, added more relevant info.

looks like the camera calibration is wrong. the cx,cy values suggest a source picture of about 4000 by 2200 pixels.

@ChristophRackwitz you are correct, the source picture is this large - 4096 x 2160

oh, in that case the intrinsics would be plausible.

I think I know what's going on. two axes are aligned with the board, and the third points into it, behind it. that would be a fitting interpretation for at least two of your pictures. the third I can't explain.

@ChristophRackwitz I agree with you that the first two kind of make sense; however, one part that doesn't make sense (from the first photo) is that there is a (small) gap between the two axis when parameters are the same and the only difference is their length? I would expect both vectors to be following exactly the same path, but one would be longer. If you wanted to see the green (y-axis) point in a different direction, try extending the axis_size to a larger value, such as 10+.

I'm guessing it could be an issue with the drawing primitives. you should drastically shorten your axes so their end points stay within view.

This has been reproduced by others and have been reported as a bug on OpenCV GitHub.

I'm guessing it could be an issue with the drawing primitives. you should drastically shorten your axes so their end points stay within view.
